# How to host Asp.Net MVC5 on IIS8.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8.5

I have MVC5 app on iis 8.5.
I'm getting 404 for my controller actions. An error is from StaticFile Handler.
How can i tell IIS to let ASP handle extension-less queries? 
I added section below, but it didn't make sense.

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

IIS Express woks fine for this queries.

Comment: Have you created a website in IIS for this?

Comment: Yes, and i'm getting index page and pages like */*.aspx.